# Create database using Alembic

Tags: python-3.x, alembic, database-versioning

I have database migrations that use `database1`. I'm using it for Alembic for migrations.

How do I create a database `database1` before running alembic?

I've created a database infrastructure using CloudFormation. And when we run the first migration, I need to run SQL `create database database1` or something equivalent.

Comment: For many backends, if you define `DBName` property on the resource CloudFormation will create the database for you: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-database-instance.html. As you haven’t mentioned the flavor of database you are using I can’t know whether this is helpful advice for you or not.

Comment: I'll have a look at this. Just FYI, I'm using RDS with MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using @SuperShoot's advice. I modified my CFT to include below snipppet

```
  "Parameters": {
    "DBName": {
      "Default": "<database name>",
      "Description": "The database name",
      "Type": "String",
      ...
    },
    ...
  }, 
  "Resources": {
   "RDSinstance": {
      "Type": "AWS::RDS::DBInstance",
      "Properties": {
        "DBName": {
          "Ref": "DBName"
        },
        ...
      }
    }, 
    ...
  }
```